# How to save value of input in a variable in JS

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to save the value of an input element in a variable. But it is returning me this - [object HTMLInputElement]

Here's my HTML -

```js
    function userSubmit() {
        let username = document.getElementById('userName');
        let password = document.getElementById('passWord');
    
        alert(username)
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>B.O.M - Create Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1 class="heading">Welcome to Bank of Maharashtra.</h1>
        </header>
    
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="sub-heading">Create your account -</h1>
    
            <div class="sub-container">
                <label for="#userName">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="" id="userName">
                <br>
                <label for="#passWord">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="" id="passWord">
                <br>
                <input onclick="userSubmit()" type="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm">
            </div>
    
            <img class="logo" src="bank_img3.webp" alt="" srcset="">
        </div>
    
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am not getting the username which i have typed in the input field. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will log the `input` itself not it's value, you need to log `input.value`

```js
function userSubmit() {
    let username = document.getElementById('userName');
    let password = document.getElementById('passWord');

    alert(username.value)
    alert(password.value)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>B.O.M - Create Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="heading">Welcome to Bank of Maharashtra.</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="sub-heading">Create your account -</h1>

        <div class="sub-container">
            <label for="#userName">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="userName">
            <br>
            <label for="#passWord">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="" id="passWord">
            <br>
            <input onclick="userSubmit()" type="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm">
        </div>

        <img class="logo" src="bank_img3.webp" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[object HTMLInputElement]` is just a string representation of your `username` object. `{value: 'Users name'}`

```
alert(JSON.stringify(username))
```

will give you an idea what you want to see.